# Migration - what happens to answers and rep?

Tags: support, migration, migrated-questions

I recently answered a question relating to SNMP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27352501/3651800).

However someone (validly) pointed out in the comments that because the poster hasn't specified that their question is relating to programming software that uses the SNMP protocol, that the question is more a sys-admin question and should be migrated:

> "I know the question has already been answered, but I'd still argue that this is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it concerns system administration, not programming. The question and answers should be migrated to serverfault.com"

In the past when developing SNMP monitoring software I have benefited from SNMP information on Stack Overflow, but I do agree with the fact that this question, as written, isn't specific to programming.

I am not active on serverfault.com, and am wondering what actually happens to answers and rep when questions are migrated?

*Note: In the case of this specific question, another user has also answered the question and their answer has been accepted in case that makes any difference to migration(?).*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, the question would be deleted, together with the reputation changes. For answers on a migrated post, deletion is instant, the question (now a stub) is deleted one month after the post is migrated.

On the target site, you'll *gain* reputation as votes are migrated along (the votes are re-cast by the Community User <sup>*</sup>). In essence, you get the same reputation (barring reputation caps). The accepted answer [remains accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8026/question-migration-does-not-maintain-accepted-answer).

There is a an [exception for questions with a negative score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31088/reset-post-score-to-0-on-migration); such questions start at 0 again on the target site. This is to off-set a "you asked this on the wrong site!" backlash, but this doesn't apply to any answers.

If you don't yet have an account on the target site, then the reputation for those votes is held until you create your account; as long as it uses the same login credentials as you use on Stack Overflow your account will automatically be associated.

Also see [Do migrated questions migrate reputation and badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges)

---

<sup>*</sup> *Yes, this means that you can upvote a migrated post twice. Once on the source site, once again on the target site. In practice, this is not really much of a problem. See [Migrated question's answers can be upvoted twice by the same user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/migrated-questions-answers-can-be-upvoted-twice-by-the-same-user)*

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question succintly! I did search for related questions before posting but didn't find the one you've linked to sorry.

Comment: @MattCoubrough: that one is on the central Meta Stack Exchange site, you would not have found it here. I don't think there is a duplicate here yet.

Comment: @MattCoubrough additionally the rep should be counted in your StackExchange total, such as on chat. So it's not gone forever, it's just gone from SO.

Comment: If I don't create an account on the target site, will my answer still be visible to users of that site? and if so, where would clicking on my user link redirect to?

Comment: @MattCoubrough Your answer will be available, your user will just look like a "deleted" user.

Comment: @MattCoubrough: the post will be there, with a grayed-out user card with no user link. The user card *does* have the original username from the source post.

Comment: @MattCoubrough: [example question](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4754/tor-router-with-obfsproxy-and-tor-dns); at the time of this comment the user has not yet claimed an account on the target site. [Another example](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83553/why-different-users-from-same-login-group-can-not-access-the-database-objects).

Comment: Thanks for the information and quick responses - am not fussed about rep, just good to know how the site works.

Comment: Ah, the votes get re-cast by the community user. So that's the reason why you can vote a second time on the same answer after it has been migrated :-)

Comment: This is subject to the same rules as standard post deletion, right? i.e. you won't actually lose the rep if the post has a score of 2 or greater. Or is this a special case?

Comment: @JeremyBanks: only if the post has a score of 3 or higher *and* is at least 60 days old is reputation retained. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/ Since posts can only be migrated if they are *younger* than 60 days you always lose the reputation on the source site.

Comment: It didn't do that for me. [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/1149470/why-does-fireftp-disconnect-automatically-after-120-seconds) that I asked was migrated from Stack Overflow to Super User and it was upvoted once and downvoted once on Stack Overflow, which made me earn 3 reputation. When it was migrated, I earned 3 reputation on Super User but got to keep 3 reputation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: I see a -3 point subtraction on December 24th when the Stack Overflow stub was deleted automatically, with the label 'migrated'. You did not keep the points.